# solr exclude html class from indexing

Tags: html, indexing, solr

Im indexing a knowledgebase with solr. The problem is, that the menu is indexed as well, so searching for a term used in the menu returns all pages.
Can I somehow tell solr to exclude a special html class from indexing?
HTML-Tags are removed, so I cant find the specified element later.

---

**EDIT:**
I added a short sample for what I want to achieve.
That is, to exclude certain html nodes (like my navigation) from beeing indexed.

Sample html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>topic-1</li>
        <li>topic-2</li>
        <li>topic-3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<main>
    <h1>Topic-1</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ament...</p>
</main>
```

What I currently get in my index from that:

```
topic-1
topic-2
topic-3

Topic-1
lorem ipsum dolor sit ament...
```

What I want to get in my index fom that:

```
Topic-1
lorem ipsum dolor sit ament...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically want to remove some of the text. You can do it on the field itself with [PatternReplace Character Filter](http://www.solr-start.com/info/analyzers/#PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory), which sits before the Tokenizer in the field type definition. That will keep it in the stored version of the field though.

Or, you could go earlier in the indexing process, and use UpdateRequestProcessor to modify the field before it is even looked at for indexing. You'd want [RegexReplace URP](http://www.solr-start.com/info/update-request-processors/#RegexReplaceProcessorFactory) for that.

Comment: one more question, the processor code shuodl be ut in my schema.xml, shouldn't it? 'Cause the sample whitespace-pattern doesnt work for me

Comment: URP is defined as part of a chain in solrconfig.xml and has to be registered on the request handler. Check your solrconfig.xml, it would have several examples of the chains and registering them.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTMLStripCharFilterFactory, which will strip HTML tags:

```
<analyzer>
  <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
  <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

Let me know if it works for yor.

Here you will find more info on the same.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory

Comment: Thats not really what I want to achieve, I added an example to my question.

Comment: try by adding <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement=""/> to your field type and try... add the correct pattern here..

Comment: I only have a content field where the whole document is stored in

Answer (score 0):

Use the [XPathEntityProcessor](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler#UploadingStructuredDataStoreDatawiththeDataImportHandler-EntityProcessors) to extract a subset of the document, matched by the provided XPath pattern.

That way you can index the actual content you want in the page (as long as it's valid XML), and ignore other common stuff such as headers/footers/etc. as well.